# Unit Testing with datatypes inputs set to MAX+1 values

Tags: c, unit-testing

I am doing unit testing for code in [c](/questions/tagged/c) language where I am thinking what could be the harm if I do not exercise testing inputs with `MAX+1` values of datatypes.

Usually, [c](/questions/tagged/c) wraps the variable value to its minimum if the value overflows its `MAX` capacity. Eg: if a `char` (range: `0-255`) is incremented after `255` will result in `0`.

Is there any example where it would be really harmful if the testing is not done `MAX+1` cases where the value rolls back to the datatype's MIN value?

Comment: Careful here, the behavior or `signed` and `unsigned` over-/under-flow is different. More specifically, signed integer overflow is *undefined*. Also remember that it's implementation-specific if `char` is a signed or unsigned type.

Comment: This is overflow in the other direction, but how about this bit of code? `size_t to_alloc = 14; to_alloc -= some_user_defined_value; Foo *bar = malloc(to_alloc);` What happens if `some_user_defined_value` is >= 14? You've just tried to allocate `SIZE_MAX` bytes, which will either fail and, if you're checking return values properly, cause an isolated error, or if you have the memory, it'll eat up a huge chunk of it.

Comment: Also, some tips to make sure this is a good question: **(1)** Remove the tag from your title. We have tags in tags here. **(2)** Clarify what you mean by "test MAX+1". Do you mean "pass MAX+1 in"? Because that won't work. If you mean "orchestrate things such that overflow is possible", state that. **(3)** Don't use the C tag marker for the language. Use the tag when you're talking about the tag; use the word (i.e. "C") when you're talking about the language. **(4)** Don't use `code markup` for things that aren't code.

Comment: Keep in mind that signedness of plain `char` is implementation specific.  Thus, prefer to use `unsigned char`.  Even better (although maybe a bit paranoid unless your code might mistakenly be compiled on unusual platforms), if you also want to be sure about the range 0-255, use `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Whether testing with `MAX+1` makes sense depends on whether you have an expectation about the behaviour of the function for `MAX+1` that you want to be honored also in case of certain potential future changes.  Assume a function `foo(uint8_t u)`: Calling such a function with an argument of, for example, `256` should usually be avoided, and you will probably get warnings.  Still, it is allowed and will mean that a value of `0` is actually passed to the function.

The situation here is that the type mismatch is handled by the compiler in a way that leads to a value change, namely in the implicit computation of a `modulo 256` operation.  If you, for some reason have code that depends on this, it can make sense to have corresponding test cases.  This will protect you against the situation that the argument type changes from `utf8_t` to, say, `utf16_t`: This change would mean that the former implicit `modulo 256` is turned into an implicit `modulo 65536`.

Please note that in my view using type conversions for modulo operations is not a good practice anyway.  That is, if a caller wants a `modulo 256` operation, then the caller should make it explict in the call, like `foo(x % 256)`.